# Upload Python script using Livy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

I am trying to find a way to push a python script using `Livy API (or client)` on the spark server. I have tried the following.

1. > curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/user/test/pi.py"}' -H
   >       "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches

, but when I
    see the logs it gives file not found because it is trying to find
    the path on the server.

2. Using Livy Python Client.

> r =
>           client.upload_pyfile("/tmp/code/test.py")

, this returns a future
        object, but the batches are not created, (I am not even sure the
        file path it is uploading to).

Basically what I want is -

1. Able to upload the file through the API, on the Spark server
   using Livy.
2. submit a batch/ run trigger. using Livy.

Comment: Did you find a solution? :)

Comment: No Luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using Livy JAVA client i am able to do the same. I have uploaded the jar to the Livy Server and submit Spark JOBS.

You can refer to the link below.
https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html

Points to note :
1. wait for the livy client to successfully upload the jar/file.
2. the jar/file should be available in the livy server or in HDFS which is accessible to livy server.